# how to return a custom error message when someone is trying to access a protected group of routes in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, routes

> question: i have several routes in my API , grouped with `middleware 'sanctum'`, like below:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']],function() {
    Route::put('/products/{id}',[ProductController::class,'update']);
    Route::post('/products',[ProductController::class,'store']);
    Route::delete('/products/{id}',[ProductController::class,'destroy']);
    Route::post('/authlogout',[AuthController::class,'authLogout']);
});
```

> now i want to show a custom error message when someone is trying to access these routes without appropriate credentials,
> currently, when someone tries to access them, he/she would get something like below:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined. in file /home/arash/LaravelTests/smart-finance/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 444
```

> but I just want a simple `['error' => 'authentication failed']` message, how can I do that? ( showing a simple response when someone tries to access any of these routes without the needed credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass header `Accept` as `application/json`.if you are not passing then you get mentioned error.For reference attached screenshot for better understanding.

After passing Accept header as application/json response

[image]

**[Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept)**

> The Accept request HTTP header indicates which content types,
> expressed as MIME types, the client is able to understand. The server
> uses content negotiation to select one of the proposals and informs
> the client of the choice with the Content-Type response header.
> Browsers set required values for this header based on the context of
> the request. For example, a browser uses different values in a request
> when fetching a CSS stylesheet, image, video, or a script.

if you are looking for custom response then you can handle by overriding exceptions.

In `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` add the following method

```
/**
 * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
        ? response()->json(['error' =>"authentication failed"], 401)
        : redirect()->guest($exception->redirectTo() ?? route('login'));
}
```